# How to add new columns if needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL databases and I'm trying to create a web stock and production database, using PHP.

In this inventory software, I am trying to create a table in which products are created and also their components inserted. But if a product has a different number of components, I wanted to know if there is any way to add more components columns from the management page of the website.

Another thing is that these components are taken from another table, and as long as a new product order is created, the quantity of those used components should be subtracted from the components table. (but this is a major issue, solving the first issue should be enough for now).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add, or remove, columns from a database table at any time.

However, I would not do this. You have to try and design a database that can handle products with a varying number of component. Normally this would be done this way:

1. Create a table for your `products`.
2. Create a table for your `components`.
3. Create a linking table `product_components`, to indicate what components a product consists off.

See: [Using linking tables for many to many relationships in MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4knkwJ6NZw)

Comment: Thank you, that's a smart solution. Hope to figure out more about the major issue.

Comment: @Mekiro Keeping track of stock is a somewhat more advance topic, and there are many possible solutions. For a SO question it would be better if you gave a clearer indication of what the database needs to do and also show us what you have tried to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about relationships in mysql. There are basically 3 types(some may say 4 though) of relationships available in a relational database like mysql.

Here according to your description you can use

1. 1 to many
2. many to many

relationship in your database. This may help you-
https://afteracademy.com/blog/what-are-the-different-types-of-relationships-in-dbms